# The use of 'Both..and'

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say:

> Both Jack and Jill have apples.

when they each only have one?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's "correct." Yes, it's also ambiguous.

If you want to be *precise* you need to rephrase it:

- Both Jack and Jill have **an** apple.
- Both Jack and Jill have **one** apple.
- Both Jack and Jill have **a single** apple.
- Jack and Jill *each* have **an** apple.
- Jack and Jill have **an** apple *apiece*.

Comment: yes and thank you. I know all those ones are correct but I was hoping to find the grammar behind it because without the grammar base it's hard for me to understand why the word "both" can mean both individually and both together. It sounds like we're jumping into the quantum mechanics here...

Comment: @rearThing English can be vague. Literally speaking, *both* could make no sense. However, in idiomatic usage, it can just mean that they both have *one or more*. Without clarification, it's not a certainly if it's more than one or not. But if it's just one, *both* still works, because you're talking about two different things that, combined, *do* have two or more things. I don't expect anybody can explain the grammar. Idiomatically, it simply is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you know they have at least one apple, but either don't know precisely how many or it's not important to distinguish that it's just one apiece, you can use the vague phrase "have apples". It doesn't imply that they have more than one, just that you aren't specific that it's only one. It's also ambiguous about whether they collectively have at least one apple or each individually does.

If it's important to specify that it's exactly one apiece, you should use more precise language, as in Jason's answer.